# magento 2 cms_index_index not working

Tags: magento2

**/app/design/frontend/some/theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block type="\Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="index.banner">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">index_banner</argument>
            <arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

It does not show `index_banner` static on the home page.

What do the error?
What needs to be done in the background or setting?

Answer (score 0):

Their mistakes

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="index_banner">
<arguments>
    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">index_banner</argument>
</arguments>
```